# Java how to get caller from separate thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

Hmm... not sure if this is possible, but how would one go about grabbing the true caller's class name (and ideally also method name) in Java if you are running on a separate thread? I want to offload the class name fetching to a separate thread (so as not to block the UI thread when i'm doing like 100+ logging operations per second).

for example:

```
class Main {
    public void callerMethod() {
        Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName(); // This gets me the caller. However, this is expensive to do on the UI Thread 100+ times per second. a call here can take up 70ms

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new SecondObject().iWantToKnowMyCaller();
            }
        }).start();
    }
}



class SecondObject {
    public void iWantToKnowMyCaller() {
        // how do i get the caller method here so that it's "callerMethod" from "Main" ?
    }
}
```

The use case is this: i'm logging a lot of data, and i don't want to block the main thread at  all. some of the logging might be quick and small data, but some might log dump a lot of stuff. the problem also is that right now, the way the code is written, there's about 600+ entry points into `callerMethod()`, so refactoring is going to be quite a challenge.

ALTERNATIVELY:

if you can prove that `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName();` is guaranteed to be a constant time operation less than like 5 ms each time, then that is acceptable to be on the main thread.

Comment: That method's caller is `run()`, not `callerMethod()`.. You want the method that created the thread that's executing? I doubt it's possible without explicitly passing the info to the thread .. not a java expert, though.

Comment: @Blorgbeard exactly. i want "callerMethod()". hmm dang :/ i thought there might have been a more dynamic way but i guess not

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Possibly you could subclass `Thread` and have it store a stack-trace in its constructor or something like that. Perhaps someone with more java knowledge than I will come along soon :)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis good question -> i want to do a lot of logging (and some logging operations make take a while to dump), and i don't want to block the main thread; thus, i spawn different threads.

Comment: A good question I feel.  A lot of new concepts for me.  Thanks!

Comment: If getting the thread's stack trace is too expensive to call from the main thread, calling it from another thread won't help; it'll be out of date by the time the other thread calls it.

Comment: @StuartMarks so in other words, you're forced to manually (or write a script) that can change all of the 600 entry points into this existing logging function?

Comment: No, I'm saying that **if** getting the stack trace is too expensive, then trying to avoid blocking the main thread by putting the operation onto another thread won't work, since it will end up logging incorrect information.

Comment: @StuartMarks oh sorry. i meant that you could pass in the class name manually, like... for example, in my Main class, i would have `public static final String myClassName = Main.class.getSimpleName();` and i would pass in `myClassName` in to all of the `methodCall(myClassName)` entry points.

Comment: @DavidT. I looked around a bit: the complexity of determining the caller is actually in LogRecord.  If you could manually set the caller via `Logger.setSourceClassName()` (to any string at all), then the LogRecord would no longer build a stack trace to look for the name of the caller.

Comment: Re "...the true caller..."  You probably have already figured this out by now, but just for the record, a thread does not have a "caller."  Of course, every thread (except for the main thread) was created by some method in some other thread, but none of that is recorded, nor does it mean anything in Java.

Comment: @jameslarge yeah.... kinda wished it was, because that's pretty useful info. :/ thanks for the note.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT:

OK, you want to AVOID the stack trace. I looked around a bit: the complexity of determining the caller is actually in `LogRecord`.  If you could manually set the caller via `Logger.setSourceClassName()` (to any string at all), then the LogRecord would no longer build a stack trace to look for the name of the caller.

```
public class ThreadTest
{
   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
      LogRecord lr = new LogRecord( Level.INFO, "Hi" );
      lr.setSourceClassName( "ThreadTest.main" );  // anything, including null
      Logger.getAnonymousLogger().log( lr );
   }
}
```

Original answer:

Subclassing `Thread` will work, but I kind of question why you'd want to do that.  For debugging maybe, but that's about the only use case I can think of.  (P.S. I had to change your offset in the stack trace.  "2" will get the caller of callerMethod -- "main" in the example below.)

```
public class ThreadTest
{
   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
      new Main().callerMethod();
   }
}

class Main {
    public void callerMethod() {
        final String callee = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName(); // This gets me the caller
        new MyThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new SecondObject().iWantToKnowMyCaller();
            }
        }){
        @Override
        public String getInvoker() { return callee; }}.start();
    }
}

abstract class MyThread extends Thread implements Invoker {    
   public MyThread( Runnable r )
   {
      super( r );
   }
}

class SecondObject {
    public void iWantToKnowMyCaller() {
        // how do i get the caller method here so that it's "callerMethod" from "Main" ?
       System.out.println( ((MyThread)(Thread.currentThread())).getInvoker() );
    }
}

interface Invoker {
   String getInvoker();
}
```

Comment: oh - sorry, i should have clarified (my question is now updated). but what i want to do is, for debugging purposes, log a ton of stuff and have the class name in the log. currently there's about 600+ entries points into this logging function. I don't want to do what you suggested because it blocks the original main thread because of the costly call to `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName();`. is there any alternatives that don't block? that's part of the reason why i chose to spawn a separate thread in the first place.

Comment: I really don't, sorry.  Like I say, this is not a normal thing to do, in any language.  You could call `Thread.setName()` and use some sort of naming scheme to denote callers or thread types, but that's all I got.

Comment: yeah, it looks like you have to statically pass the String in so as to avoid expensive computations :/ unfortunately this meant that i had to write a script that can parse out the java code in order to write up like a Tag for every class. thanks

Comment: well, i'm going to keep my question open for now, in case anyone comes up with anything else (and you'll likely get more upvotes with it open anyways). and will prolly accept your answer if there's not better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class ThreadTest{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new Main().callerMethod();
        }
    }
class Main{
    public void callerMethod() {
        new Thread(new MyRunnable(new Throwable())).start();
    }
    class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

        Throwable t;

        MyRunnable(Throwable t) {
            this.t = t;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            StackTraceElement[] ses = t.getStackTrace();
            System.out.println(ses[0].getClassName() + ":" + ses[0].getMethodName() );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you still have the method `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName();` on the main thread, and that's what i was trying to avoid. do you have an alternative? :/

Comment: I don't know wheather `new Throwable` is expensive for you

Comment: is `new Throwable` accurate? i'm thinking it might be still expensive because of the `getStackTrace`

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases.

1. You extended `Thread.` If you override `Thread.start(),` you can peek the stack trace there.
2. You implemented `Runnable.` In this case you can't know, in principle. All you can know is who created the `Runnable,` by peeking the stack trace in the constructor, but that isn't necessarily the same method that started the thread.

Comment: how expensive is peeking the stack trace in `Thread.start`? and is that even accurate if i peek there? (like will it be out of date?) i've profiled some of the calls to `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName();` and on Android, it is sometimes 70ms per call. that's somewhat unacceptable to be doing many times on the main UI thread in certain cases.